# C# - ASP NET.CORE 3.1 - problem with update record's in table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, permissions

I have a problem after publishing my API for example hosting - I can add and load records - however, I cannot modify and delete records from the array - I use the database via phpmyadmin and unfortunately there is no option to grant permissions.

In the API, I have the entire functionality of user authorization and authentication with token generation - everything works very well on IIS - however, when I release the API into the world and want to connect using a desktop program - there is no possibility to modify records and delete records. When I use the control to modify or delete records, I get the answer: InternalServerError (500).

1. What could I forget?
2. Can I give API privileges to everyone in advance for testing?
3. The problem lies with MySQL and phpmyadmin? How to add permissions?
4. Additional tips?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: I think that the problem is not on the API side, but on the MySQL permission settings - db user settings. Can you delete record in phpmyadmin using same user as your API?

Comment: Can't delete it - but you can add and load it - when I run the same API and program on IIS, everything is fine. For testing in ConnectionString's I have defined administrator login details and it did not help after publishing. And in phpmyadmin I don't have the option to change settings and permissions.

Comment: Any idea for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem - someone may find a solution, please:

```html
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="SmoothHandler" />
      <remove name="RestfulUrlMapModule" />
      <remove name="PlaylistHandler" />
      <remove name="BitrateModule" />
      <remove name="LiveStreamingHandler" />
</modules>
```